# Pull out subset of data, take the mean, make a new dataframe. Is there an easier way?

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I have data like this:

```
Site <- c(1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2)
Year <- c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2)
count <- c(0,1,0,3,1,1,2,4,1,0)
Species <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
df <- data.frame(Site, Year, count, Species)
```

So it looks like this:

```
  Site Year count Species
1     1    1     0       1
2     2    1     1       1
3     2    1     0       1
4     1    2     3       1
5     2    2     1       1
6     1    1     1       2
7     2    1     2       2
8     1    2     4       2
9     1    2     1       2
10    2    2     0       2
```

As you can see, only in some years were counts taken more than once at the same site, and there are two different species.
What I want to do is:

1) find the counts that were taken at the same site in the same year

2) take the mean of those counts

3) Put mean counts into a dataframe or vector that I can use later for plotting.

I've been playing with it and all I've come up with so far is some sort of complicated, stacked for loop that I have no idea how to finish:

```
for (year in 1:length(df$Year)) {
    for (site in 1:length(df$Site))
        subset(Site==site & Year==year)
        if (nrow > 1) mean(count)
```

But now i'm stuck because I don't know how to get the new mean into a new dataframe, populated with site, year, and species info.

Any ideas? Or is my approach all wrong to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Site, Year, Species) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(count))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
#Groups: Site, Year [?]
#
#   Site  Year Species  mean
#  (dbl) (dbl)   (dbl) (dbl)
#1     1     1       1   0.0
#2     1     1       2   1.0
#3     1     2       1   3.0
#4     1     2       2   2.5
#5     2     1       1   0.5
#6     2     1       2   2.0
#7     2     2       1   1.0
#8     2     2       2   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a split-apply-combine problem.  Specialized libraries like `dplyr` and `data.table` dominate the space, but this problem is straightforward enough in base R using `aggregate`.

```
> aggregate(count ~ Site + Year + Species, data=df, mean)
  Site Year Species count
1    1    1       1   0.0
2    2    1       1   0.5
3    1    2       1   3.0
4    2    2       1   1.0
5    1    1       2   1.0
6    2    1       2   2.0
7    1    2       2   2.5
8    2    2       2   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your question that you only want to group by Site and Year (not species)?? Anyway, assuming that, and respecting the need to exclude means where there is only one observation, here's a data.table solution.

```
# modify example slightly so that we can demo exclusion for N=1
df <- df[-1,]    # remove first row so Year,Site=(1,1) has only one instance

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,list(mean.count=mean(count), .N), by=list(Site,Year)][N>1]
#    Site Year mean.count N
# 1:    2    1   1.000000 3
# 2:    1    2   2.666667 3
# 3:    2    2   0.500000 2
```

Comment: The question is rather confusing but I think OP wants to group by `Species` too: "But now i'm stuck because I don't know how to get the new mean into a new dataframe, populated with site, year, and species info"

Comment: @StevenBeaupré perhaps OP means Site and Year and count of Species??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure of what are you trying to do, but as per my understanding, you want to get the mean of the counts for every site-year combination.

If that is the case, you can do this in a single step using the `aggregate` function:

```
new.df <- aggregate( data = df, FUN = mean, count ~ Year + Site )

  Year Site    count
1    1    1 0.500000
2    2    1 2.666667
3    1    2 1.000000
4    2    2 0.500000
```

If what you want to group by all three variables, then:

```
new.df <- aggregate( data = df, FUN = mean, count ~ Year + Site + Species )

  Year Site Species count
1    1    1       1   0.0
2    2    1       1   3.0
3    1    2       1   0.5
4    2    2       1   1.0
5    1    1       2   1.0
6    2    1       2   2.5
7    1    2       2   2.0
8    2    2       2   0.0
```

Please note that you can add the na.rm parameter aswell.